# Excel forumla to recognize new tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my excel workbook I'm setting up a summary tab that will simply sum the contents of the same cell on the following tabs. This in itself is pretty easy I know but I need the forumla to recognize when another tab is added and update to include the data found there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: need to use a macro and hook in to NewSheet event of workbook. Google ro learn about macros in excel

Comment: There is no such formula. You could conceivably do something with the `NewSheet` event, and this will require also re-writing ALL of the formulas that need to be recalculated (this part can be done via macro).  Please show us what you have tried so fare, or try to work through this method and if you get stuck, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to define the first and last sheets and use a 3D formula. Make a sheet named "First" and one named "Last". Don't put anything on these sheets, they're just bookends for the real sheets.  Then you can use

```
=SUM(First:Last!A10)
```

to sum cell A10 for all the sheets in between them. New sheets added in between them will automatically be included. Of course, someone could add a sheet outside that range, but to deal with that you'll need code and the NewSheet event as @tgkprog commented.